# Where is CreateWindowEx()?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, createwindowex

I'm trying to understand how winapi works. I just started on writing my first few apps. Now I am curious about the function "CreateWindowEx()" I wish to know what is written inside this function, but all I can find are the arguments for calling it and the parameters for it. So I decided to look for this function within the h files, but I can't find it. Can someone please help?

Comment: You can't see the implementation for CreateWindowEx().  It's buried in the implementation of the operating system.

Answer (score 4):

It's *declared* in:

```
Winuser.h (include Windows.h)
```

but Windows isn't open-source, so I doubt you'll find the implementation (unless you work for MS and have access to the code). You can step in the dissasembly, but I doubt you'll find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx):

> Header Winuser.h (include Windows.h)
>
> Library User32.lib
>
> DLL User32.dll

That means the function is **declared** in winuser.h, **linked to** by user32.lib, and **implemented** in user32.dll.